# Viewing Expressions in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have just started using Xcode 4.2, and am finding myself very frustrated with it.  I am trying to view an expression but it always tells me 'invalid expression'.  For example, I have the following iOS code:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect rect = { 0, 0, 480, 320 };
    …
```

If I put a breakpoint on a line after the declaration and initialization of rect, right-click on the 'Local' window, choose 'Add Expression' and then enter 'rect', the variable displays in the 'Local' window, but it says 'invalid expression'. This all used to work in the previous version of Xcode (which had an explicit 'Expressions' window). The declaration of rect is not the issue. I don't seem to be able to view ANY local variable, regardless of its declaration.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why did you like this coding style?
Who didn't you use CGRectMake(x, y, w, h) instead?

Comment: There seems to be more going on here than this.  I find that XCode is crashing quite frequently.  I had a number of issues after I first installed it, and even more now.  I am wondering if I have a bad install.  Should I uninstall and reinstall?  Can I have both XCode 4 and XCode 3 installed at the same time?

Comment: @JohnGaby, what debugger are you using? I have found that some of Xcode's debugging features work with GDB, but not LLDB. Switch to GDB and see if you can view expressions.

Comment: John Gaby asked: "Can I have both Xcode 4 and Xcode 3 installed at the same time?"; the answer is "yes". Note however that if you use the command line tools that you should use 'xcode-select' to setup everything property when you switch between Xcode versions.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk Didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

if you still dont want to change your debugger, you can right click in the expression and print the description, very helpfull